# Bind9 on Ubuntu (proof of concept question)

Tags: dns, bind

I want to set up Bind9 as a local DNS. Its function would be:

- Allow a local-network Wiki and blog to have their own URLs.
- Forward other requests to a pair of external DNS servers.

Is this viable with a local Bind server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Bind is an advanced and more or less feature-complete dns-server. Whatever tricks you want to do with DNS, can probably be done with Bind.

It sounds like you want to set up Bind with a authoritative zone (master zone), and one or more forwarders.

It *may* be easier to configure `dnsmasq`, but Bind will certainly work in this scenario.